# How do you download an internet radio stream given by URL?

Tags: audio-recording, internet-radio

I tried by downloading using Chrome when I see a link in a Web page, but I don't see the file anywhere and if I choose cancel, it apparently removes any recording.

Comment: There is a problem with internet radio streams: they have no end, so browser will continue downloading until an error occurs. Therefore from browser perspective the download will never complete. What happens with the data if you cancel depends on the used web browser. You should better search for an app that is specialized on audio stream download and may be saves them in certain (e.g. hourly) chunks.

Answer (score 1):

In [Cloud Radio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MSoft.cloudradio) you can add new channel by URL and schedule at most 23 h 59 min continuous recording, and you can set the recording repeat on given weekdays.

Comment: The application doesn't seem to be very reliable though.